# Show week number of the year in custom format

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I'm wondering if there is any custom date  format (Excel or VBA) that shows week number (of the year) in a date.

Here is to clarify what I mean: Assume

```
A1 = "02/03/2020  13:19:57"
```

I have This custom format on A1:

```
[$-en-US]ddd, mmm dd, hh:mm
```

The result is:

```
Mon, Mar 02, 13:19
```

So I'd like to have week number at the end:

```
Mon, Mar 02, 13:19, 10
```

BTW need "A1" to remain as Date

Appreciate any help.

Solved Thanks to @FaneDuru

```
WeekNum = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(ActiveCell, vbMonday)
With ActiveCell
    .NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]ddd, mmm dd, hh:mm" & """, W" & WeekNum & """"
    Debug.Print "Week num: " & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(.Value)
    Debug.Print Year(.Value)
End With
```

Comment: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/667725-format-date-cell-with-week-number.html

Comment: You may want to consider putting the week number in a separate cell next to it so that you can preserve it being in a date format still.

Comment: You could use this in **VBA** to get the week number: `WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(DateValue(oSht.Range("A1")))` (where `oSht` is your sheet). You could also use `WeekNum` as a formula to get the desired result. Saying that, i do agree with @braX: you should consider a separate column to preserve your source column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, Please. It will remain Data format, but the week number will be something built. It can be extracted from the date...

```
Sub testNumberFormatSpec()
  With ActiveCell
    .Formula = "=Now()"
    .NumberFormat = "ddd, mmm dd, hh:mm"" Week " & _
       WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(ActiveCell.value, vbMonday) & """"
     Debug.Print "Week num: " & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(.value)
     Debug.Print Year(.value)
  End With
End Sub
```

What I tried to suggest is the fact that this format cannot by just filled down for other cells. It must be built using the above code. The week number is added as string at the end of the date format. It can be extracted from the existing date value, but not to be applied like format to another range. In fact, the code can be introduced in `Worksheet_Change` event in order to adapt the format of each changed cells... Of course, in a previously defined range.

Comment: @Afshin Davoudy: Your `ActiveCell` had to contain date...  But, please refresh the page and test the updated code. It is keeping the date format...

Comment: I've changed your code a little bit to meet my needs, but it works fine. Thank you so much. btw how can I put the word "Week" before week number?

Comment: @Afshin Davoudy: Glad to here I could help! Can you share (editing your question) your solution? I never needed such an approach, but who know? Maybe in the future I will, or I will be able to help somebody else...

Comment: The question has been updated. PS. I needed a cell that updates with current date (ans week number of course) when a specific cell filled. But also needed to set week number when user changes the date manually. So, I've decided to set current date and week number in separated macros.

Comment: @Afshin Davoudy:  Nice, but you can input the code in `Worksheet_Change` event and adapt it as you need for any date entry. Of course, for a range preliminary defined...

Comment: Another question: Is there any way to put the word "Week" in to the format, like: Mon, Mar 02, 13:19, Week 10

Comment: @Afshin Davoudy: Yes. Since, it is a built string, yes. I will adapt my answer accordingly...